# .NET Service - Analysing Development vs Test performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, cpu

I have a .NET REST API written using C# MVC5.

The API uses repository that fire hoses necessary data from database, then analyses it and transforms into usable model. The transformation uses a lot of linq to model the data.

On dev (Windows 10), i7 8 core @ 3.7ghz, 32gb ram. it takes 10 secs for large test range.

Running on a VM (Windows 2008R2) virtual xeon with 8 virtual  cores @ 2.99ghz, 8GB RAM takes 300 seconds (5 mins).

Neither exhaust memory, and neither are CPU-bound (CPU touches 50% on the VM, and barely noticed on dev box.)

Same database, code etc.

The API makes use of async api to load some peripheral data whilst it's doing primary job, so I could put some logs in to log time I guess.

What are the common techniques for tackling this problem? Can the CPU speed really be making that much difference?

thanks

EDIT: 
FOllowing comment by Pieter, I've increased the VM's memory to 12GB and monitored the performance of the VM whilst executing the operation. It's not the best visual aid (screen shot of TM end of op), but what it did show what that the vCPUs never really went above ~60% and memory - apart from a few mb at beginning of request, never went above 2.7GB.

[image]

If IIS / .NET / my operation is not maxing out the resources, what is taking so long?

Comment: A common technique might be to run nightly builds of your usable model and then use that model during the day, though I am unsure if that would fit your process? Is it still good if data is build into a usable model only once a night? Otherwise, I guess a review of your current implementation and possible bottlenecks might come in handy

Comment: thanks for comment icepickle. the arguments for the request include a time, and i can get round the majority of use cases by pre-building/caching the response.  but I'm really trying to find out why such a difference - Virtual Win 2008 vs Physical win 10 (similar vcpu/cores and both running within memory constraints)

Comment: What is the memory working set for the process? The Dev box has 4x the memory of the production VM.

Comment: Guest memory consumption didn't go above 6gb.  I've restarted vm and now running the operation with task manager running to view cpu and mem. I will post screenshot in main question in a few mins

Comment: @PieterGeerkens so increased v mem to 12GB and monitored resources during op.  See my EDIT.  Just under 5 minutes.  Could it just be grunt of dev WS over Virtual hosts? 5mins v 10 seconds is a big difference though